# Application locks up when it should get a runtime error during debug

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I develop windows applications in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2008. Recently I reloaded my pc and moved from XP to Windows 7 64 bit. Now when I am debugging, when I should get a runtime error, the executable instead locks up when it should bring up the code with the line that it crashed on like you'd expect in debug.

This doesn't happen all the time, only when I get a runtime error in a separate assembly that is not in the assembly I'm debugging. It used to work fine, but now it locks up. If I run the executable outside of Visual Studio (without debug) I at least get a runtime error like you'd hope for. I don't even get that when debugging. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the runtime error you're receiving in 'normal' conditions???

Comment: I've had this problem with every error I've had. It could be any error. For instance, I've tested it with a divide by zero error and it happens.

Answer (score 1):

any chance you might need to change your project settings to compile for 64 bit architecture ? 
(maybe you already know where this is, but  > go to project properties > build tab > platform dropdown )